# Is it possible to mock 'pthread_mutex_lock' with Google Mock?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, pthreads, googlemock

I am having problems when mocking **pthread_mutex_lock**, I already mock **pthread_create** successfully but I am having a SEGFAULT when trying to mock pthread_mutex_lock:

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
> 0x00000000004e35f0 in MockPthread::pthread_mutex_lock (this=0x7cbac0,
> gmock_a1=0x7b7b20 testing::internal::g_gmock_mutex)

in my pthread_mock.h:

```
#include <pthread.h>
class MockPthread{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD4(pthread_create, int(pthread_t *, const pthread_attr_t *, void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *));
    MOCK_METHOD1(pthread_mutex_lock, int(pthread_mutex_t *)); // This is where GDB stops with SIGSEGV
};

void MockPthread_setMock(MockPthread &pthread_mock);
```

Then, in pthread_mock.cpp:

```
#include "pthread_mock.h"

static MockPthread* mock;

void MockPthread_setMock(MockPthread &pthread_mock) {
    mock = &pthread_mock;
}

int pthread_create (pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr, void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg) {
    return mock->pthread_create(thread, attr, start_routine, arg);
}

int pthread_mutex_lock(pthread_mutex_t *mutex){
    return mock->pthread_mutex_lock(mutex);
}
```

So in my test.cpp I can do as:

```
#include "pthread_mock.h"
MockPthread mock_pthread;
MockPthread_setMock(mock_pthread);
```

And set expectations like this:

```
EXPECT_CALL(mock_pthread, pthread_create(_,_,_,_))
    .WillOnce(DoAll(
                SaveArg<2>(&cllbk),
                Return(1)
                ))
```

So, do you have an idea on why mocking pthread_mutex_lock causes a seg fault ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would be inclined to guess that the problem is with the code under test, not the mock.  It might be helpful to run the test in a debugger so as to capture a stack trace and have a look around at the context and data of the segfault.  We, however, are unlikely to be able to provide a an explanation of your problem without a [mre].

Comment: @JohnBollinger But the code under test is not being executed yet, I ran it with GDB and the program stops in that lineMOCK_METHOD1(pthread_mutex_lock, int(pthread_mutex_t *)); // This is where GDB stops with SIGSEGV

Comment: How can the code under test not be running?  That would be what calls your mocks.  If it's not running, then execution should not be reaching your mocks in the first place.

Comment: The test.cpp setups the mocks and everything but the code under test is not being executed when the crash occurs.

Comment: Let me put it a different way.  Something is *calling* the `MockPthread::pthread_mutex_lock()` method.  I assert that nothing ought to be doing that other than the code under test (indirectly, through your version of `pthread_mutex_lock()`), but in the end, it doesn't matter so much.  The point is that the problem is almost certainly in the caller, not the mock.

Comment: Side note: I didn't pay much attention to this on account of the fact that you said your `pthread_create` mock was working, but do note that mocks for pthreads functions need to have C linkage, like the functions being mocked.  I don't see the needed declarations for that in the code presented.

Comment: Additionally: do watch out for the possibility of `pthread_mutex_lock()` being called before `MockPthread_setMock()`.  I disregarded this possibility, too, on the basis of the claim that the `pthread_create` mock works, but that was perhaps a bit hasty.